# Javascript image carousel I created throwing errors and not sliding to next image how do I fix them?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I made a carousel using HTML CSS and vanilla javascript and assumed I defined everything correctly, but it gives me these two errors in the console. I think it can't read the style and html button element but after checking I can't see where I went wrong.

```
script.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at moveToSlide (script.js:33)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (script.js:104)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>


  <div class="carousel">
      <button class="carousel__button carousel__button--left is-hidden">

          <img src="left.svg" alt="">


      </button>
<!--      part of the carousel-->


      <div class="carousel__track-container">
<!--          elements in carousel-->
          <ul class="carousel__track">
            <li class="carousel__slide">
                <img class="carousel__image current-slide" src="lake.jpg" alt="">
            </li>
            <li class="carousel__slide">
                <img class="carousel__image" src="woods.jpg" alt="">
            </li>
            <li class="carousel__slide">
                <img class="carousel__image" src="porsche.jpg" alt="">
            </li>


          </ul>



      </div>

      <button class="carousel__button carousel__button--right">

          <img src="right.svg" alt="">

      </button>
         <div class="carousel__nav">

         <div class="carousel__indicator current-slide"></div>
         <div class="carousel__indicator"></div>
         <div class="carousel__indicator"></div>

        </div>
  </div>



<script src="script.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the js code

```js
const track = document.querySelector('.carousel__track');
const slides = Array.from(track.children);
const nextButton = document.querySelector('.carousel__button--right');
const prevButton = document.querySelector('.carousel__button--left');

const dotsNav = document.querySelector('.carousel__nav');
const dots = Array.from(dotsNav.children);

const slideWidth = slides[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;

const setSlidePosition = (slide, index) => {
    slide.style.left = slideWidth * index + 'px';
};

slides.forEach(setSlidePosition);

const moveToSlide = (track, currentSlide, targetSlide) => {
   track.style.transform = 'translateX(-' + targetSlide.style.left + ')';

    //when using class list no dot
    currentSlide.classList.remove('current-slide');
    targetSlide.classList.add('current-slide');
}



const updateDots = (currentDot, targetDot) => {
    currentDot.classList.remove('current-slide');
    targetDot.classList.add('current-slide');


}


const hideShowArrows = (slides, prevButton, nextButton, targetIndex) => {
     if (targetIndex === 0){
        prevButton.classList.add('is-hidden');
        nextButton.classList.remove('is-hidden');
    } else if (targetIndex === silides.length -1) {
        prevButton.classList.remove('is-hidden');
        nextButton.classList.add('is-hidden');
    } else {
        prevButton.classList.remove('is-hidden');
        nextButton.classList.remove('is-hidden');
    }
}


prevButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const currentSlide = track.querySelector('.current-slide');
    const prevSlide = currentSlide.previousElementSibling;
    const currentDot = dotsNav.querySelector('.current-slide');
    const prevDot = currentDot.previousElementsibling


    moveToSlide(track, currentSlide, prevSlide);
    updateDots(currentDot, prevDot);

    hideShowArrows(slides, prevButton, nextButton, t);
});

nextButton.addEventListener('click', e => {

    const currentSlide = track.querySelector('.current-slide');
    const nextSlide = currentSlide.nextElementSibling;
    const currentDot = dotsNav.querySelector('.current-slide');

    const nextDot = currentDot.nextElementSibling;



    moveToSlide(track, currentSlide, nextSlide);
    updateDots(currentDot, nexDot);

    hideShowArrows(slides, prevButton, nextButton, targetIndex);

});

dotsNav.addEventListener('click', e => {

    const targetDot = e.target.closest('button');


    if(!targetDot) return;



    //know what current slide is
    const currentSlide = track.querySelector('.current-slide');
    const currentDot = dotsNav.querySelector('.current-slide')
    const targetIndex = dots.findIndex(dot => dot === targetDot);
    const targetSlide = slides[targetIndex];

    moveToSlide (track, currentSlide, targetSlide);
    updateDots(currentDot, updateDots);

    if (targetIndex === 0){
        prevButton.classList.add('is-hidden');
        nextButton.classList.remove('is-hidden');
    } else if (targetIndex === silides.length -1) {
        prevButton.classList.remove('is-hidden');
        nextButton.classList.add('is-hidden');
    } else {
        prevButton.classList.remove('is-hidden');
        nextButton.classList.remove('is-hidden');
    }
})
```

any ideas, I have the html and css code I can create a snippet with too. 
Thanks.

Comment: How are you including your script tag?

Comment: external file, like this <script src="script.js"></script>

Comment: To check this you'd also need to include the HTML. Apparently, the `track` variable is `undefined`, so it can't set the style. You could use `console.log()` messages in your functions to see what elements are being found. And you can use `addEventListener("load", ...)` before executing your code, to make sure all the DOM content is actually there.

Comment: @N.Mustafa try deferring the script until the page has been parsed by adding a `defer` tag: `<script src="" defer></script>`

Otherwise, as @Kokodoko said, we need to see the HTML.